# How to send a Json Object in java

Tags: java, json, client-server

so I have a java Server Client Socket running, and I am trying to send a Json Object over the line. I run into a problem when I try to send the Json object. Because the Json object is not serialized. So what I do then is send it as a String to the Client, this works, but I need to rebuild the Json Object tree.

**How do I rebuild a Json Object Tree after I send a Stringed version of the Json Object?**

here is some code

Server Side

```
//Snip
    //Inside loop
    out.writeObject(clientData.toString());
//End Snip
```

Client Side

```
//Snip
    while ((fromServer = objectIO.readObject()) != null) {
            commands.interpretServer(fromServer);
            sleepThread(100);
            if (fromServer.equals("Bye.")){
                break;
            }
    }
//End Snip
```

The Json is generated semi manually

```
clientData = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("playerX", playerContent[0][1])
                    .add("playerY", playerContent[1][1])
                    .add("playerTotalHealth", playerContent[2][1])
                    .add("playerCurrentHealth", playerContent[3][1])
                    .add("playerTotalMana", playerContent[4][1])
                    .add("playerCurrentMana", playerContent[5][1])
                    .add("playerExp", playerContent[6][1])
                    .add("playerExpTNL", playerContent[7][1])
                    .add("playerLevel", playerContent[8][1])
                    .add("points", playerContent[9][1])
                    .add("strength", playerContent[10][1])
                    .add("dexterity", playerContent[11][1])
                    .add("constitution", playerContent[12][1])
                    .add("intelligence", playerContent[13][1])
                    .add("wisdom", playerContent[14][1])
                    .add("items", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                            .add(items[0]).add(items[1])
                            .add(items[2]).add(items[3])
                            .add(items[4]).add(items[5])
                            .add(items[6]).add(items[7])
                            .add(items[8]).add(items[9])
                            .add(items[10]).add(items[11])
                            .add(items[12]).add(items[13])
                            .add(items[14]).add(items[15])
                            .add(items[16]).add(items[17])
                            .add(items[18]).add(items[19])
                            .add(items[20]).add(items[21])
                            .add(items[22]).add(items[23])
                            .build())
                    .add("currentMapX", playerContent[16][1])
                    .add("currentMapY", playerContent[17][1])
                    .build();
```

Output the client receives

```
{"playerX":"2*32","playerY":"7*32","playerTotalHealth":"100","playerCurrentHealth":"100","playerTotalMana":"50","playerCurrentMana":"50","playerExp":"0","playerExpTNL":"20","playerLevel":"1","points":"0","strength":"1","dexterity":"1","constitution":"1","intelligence":"1","wisdom":"1","items":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"],"currentMapX":"0","currentMapY":"0"}
```

Comment: Use a JSON parser/generator.

Comment: Show us what you tried, and what does the string that you send look like?  Are you generating the JSON by hand?

Comment: What does the clientData.toString() do?  generate JSON?

Comment: clientData is a Json Object, when I run toString() it turns it into the Stringed form. I will upload the output

Answer (score 3):

Use a library like Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson.  With this you can generate as well as parse the JSON.

An alternative to Jackson is Genson: http://owlike.github.io/genson/

Comment: can you please check my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024158/how-to-access-github-graphql-api-using-java]